# What's the best way to store images for a carousel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Ruby on Rails. I'll have two carousels on my landing page, and I want to know what is the best way to store and display these images:

**Option One**

Put the images in `assets/images` and show them in the carousel. If this is a good way, can I loop through the images in the folder or I'll have to specify each one of the files?

**Option Two**

Create a model with an image column and loop through the images that have some specific attribute?

**Other Three**

Something else

Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I hate to have text or files on the database because you can't just `grep` for something when you need it.

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: have your images in a folder like the accepted answer :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend you not place them directly in the `assets/images` directory because you will likely add application-specific images to the app at some point that you won't want in your carousel. A folder like `app/assets/images/carousel`, for example, allows you to more easily determine which images belong in the carousel.

In your controller, add something like the following:

```
@images = Dir.glob("app/assets/images/carousel/*.{gif,jpg,png}")
```

Then, in your view, you could add something like the following (assuming ERB)

```
<% @images.each do |image| %>
   <%= image_tag "carousel/#{image.split('/').last}" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You should add the file extension, if not it'll read the non-image files (like .gitkeep files): `Dir.glob("app/assets/images/carousel/*.jpg")`

Comment: Is there a way to store image dynamically into app/assets/images ? Reason I am asking is I will be building a e-com site with a admin console, where the admin can change the images that should come in carousel according to the season or depends on sale.