# View helper method that lists images in a directory with `Dir.glob` and `each ... do` not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My goal is to be able to include a helper method in my Rails 4 project that will list all images in a particular directory in a view so that I don't have to manually add `image_tags` each time I add a new image.

I've come across [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462752/whats-the-best-way-to-store-images-for-a-carousel) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081109/rails-how-to-list-all-images-in-a-folder-using-the-image-tag) of this, but for my purposes I'd like to allocate this job to a helper method, and I can't for the life of me understand why this isn't working.

**myapp_helper.rb**

```
module MyAppHelper
  def list_logos(clss)
    logos = Dir.glob("engines/myapp/app/assets/images/myapp/logos/*.{gif,png,jpg}")
    logos.each do |logo|
      content_tag("li", class: clss) do
        image_tag logo.gsub("engines/myapp/app/assets/images/", "")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= list_logos("companies__company") %>
```

This just prints out the `Dir.glob` array. Before, I had tried `image_tag("myapp/logos/#{image.split('/').last}"` to no avail, and so I thought I might have better luck with the `gsub` method. Nope.

Funny thing is, if, in my helper method, I just write:

```
logos = Dir.glob("engines/myapp/app/assets/images/myapp/logos/*.{gif,png,jpg}")
image_tag logos.sample.gsub("engines/petitions/app/assets/images/", "")
```

the image renders fine, which leads me to believe that it's the `logos.each` iteration which is failing.

I'm stumped. I'll add that this is an engines-based project that I've inherited, and I'm a relative newbie when it comes to Ruby *and* Rails, so I very well could be missing something simple. Yay! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate and return the tags. Try something like this:

```
module MyAppHelper
  def list_logos(clss)
    logos = Dir.glob("engines/myapp/app/assets/images/myapp/logos/*.{gif,png,jpg}")
    logos.map do |logo|
      content_tag("li", class: clss) do
        image_tag logo.gsub("engines/myapp/app/assets/images/", "")
      end
    end.join
  end
end
```

Also, since you're constructing HTML in the helper, you'll need to use `html_safe` in the template:

```
<%= list_logos("companies__company").html_safe %>
```

Oh, and the reason you saw the result of `Dir.glob` is that `each` returns the object it's called on.

Comment: Ahh, I see! So the `each` method just returns the original object on which it's acting (in this case, an array of strings), whereas I want to return one big 'ole string. And I see that here, `map` is preferred over `each`. More to research :). EDIT: posted before I saw your edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
module MyAppHelper
  def list_logos(clss)
    logos = Dir.glob("engines/myapp/app/assets/images/myapp/logos/*.{gif,png,jpg}")
    list_items = logos.map do |logo|
      content_tag("li", class: clss) do
        image_tag logo.gsub("engines/myapp/app/assets/images/", "")
      end
    end
    list_items.join
  end
end
```